# how to delete indexedDB after 2 hours or less using timestamp Dexie.js instead of date search

Tags: javascript, time, indexeddb, dexie

Am using `Dexie.js` on my website to cache ajax response, but i would love to delete some old cache after 5 minites or more depending on the useage.
So mu question is how do i delete cached data using time not date.

Saving to cache indexedDB

```
function getTodayDate(){
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1; 
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    if(dd<10) {dd = '0'+dd} 
    if(mm<10) {mm = '0'+mm} 
    return  mm + '-' + dd + '-' + yyyy;
}

var time = new Date().getTime();
db.product.put({nameId: "abc163", text: "hello world", cacheUrl: "example.com", timestamp: time, date: getTodayDate()})
.catch(function(error) {
     console.log ("Ooops: " + error);
});
```

Here is how i delete using date search

```
db.product.where("date").below(getTodayDate()).delete()
.then(function (deleteCount) {
    console.log( "Deleted " + deleteCount + " objects");
});
```

But i what to delete by time maybe after 1 hour, 60 hours or less, i don't know if is possible but i think it can be done.

```
function checkTime(){
    var delete_after = 300;
    //How do i check it
}

db.product.where("timestamp").below(checkTime()).delete()
.then(function (deleteCount) {
    console.log( "Deleted " + deleteCount + " objects");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I did this for keeping records fresh, I don't want anything older than four weeks, so I just used this:

```
db.records.where('timestamp').below(Date.now() - 2419200000).delete()
```

Seems straightforward - are you trying to do something more complicated?

Comment: That nice, but i want something like hours after 1 day i will cache new data

Comment: With Dexie, the filter function is a pure Javascript array function, so you can do anything with the object fields before deleting. So db.records.filter(obj => blah).delete(); This gives you all the flexibility you need to create the filter function.

Comment: That good,but how do i calculate if the cache time is more than a giving duration?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Tell me exactly what types of records you want to delete.

Comment: I mean a function that can return when to delete a cache, you made this `Date.now() - 2419200000` for 4 weeks but i want something like 15 hours

Comment: So 15 hours in milliseconds is 57600000. Just swap the numbers.

Comment: Thank, but how do i gennerate it automatically without having to pass it this way maybe `var duration = 15;/*hours*/ var timer = (duration ..........)`. Because if i want 5 hours i will have to create convert 5h to milliseconds and so on.  That why i want to wrap it in a function and use it by passing hour to the function

Comment: @tom when/where do you run this query? db.records.where('timestamp').below(Date.now() - 2419200000).delete()